# How can I set up an Expo app to work behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to try to React Native / Expo App on my company PC (Windows).

I was following all guides on Proxy setup and settings, but I'm still getting this error.

`Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.`

I've added proxies to **.npmrc** [file](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/troubleshooting-proxies/#command-line-application-proxy-configuration), also tried changing **URL Server** by this command_

`export EXPO_PACKAGER_PROXY_URL=http://expo.dev npx expo start`

Tried to set up [tunneling](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/#tunneling), but unsuccessfully.

Has anyone encountered similar problems and found solution to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this same issue at work. I have discovered a few work-arounds through trial and error.

1. use `yarn` to import expo modules. This seems to help with the dependency issues that expo imports often have.
2. set yarn config to `yarn config set strict-ssl false -g` if you are receiving SSL errors.
3. run this command - `$Env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` if you are receiving `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` errors. <--this is not 100% safe because makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification -- use at your own risk.

The `Unable to reach Expo servers...` error still renders, but I can just ignore it and continue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first! I tried same steps, but somehow don't work for me.